# What is the right direction of using "*.isInstance"?

Tags: java, identity, proof, isinstance

I am confused every time I read the Java Documentation again to that.
So please try to help me in your own words.

```
List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<Parent>();
//Child extends Parent...
list.add(new Child());
...
...
for(Parent p: list){
    if(p.getClass().isInstance(Child)){
            Child c = (Child) p;
            c.execFuncNonExistingInParent();
    }
}
```

Just wanna proof the Objects inheritances from Parent, to avoid Cast Problems.

```
if(p.getClass().isInstance(Child.class))
```

or

```
if(Child.class.isInstance(p.getClass()))
```

Greatings Oekel

Comment: `if(p.getClass().isInstance(Child.class))` or `if(Child.class.isInstance(p.getClass()))` is the same. like (1==(2-1)) or ((2-1)==1)

Comment: pClass.isInstance(child) return true means child is an instance of pClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not checking what you want to check *either* way round. You want:

```
if (Child.class.isInstance(p))
```

That's equivalent to:

```
if (p instanceof Child)
```

... except you can specify the class to check dynamically, rather than it being fixed at compile-time. If you *do* know the class at compile-time (as in your example) then just use the `instanceof` operator instead.

For `isInstance`, it's easy to tell which way round it goes, once you've remembered it as being equivalent to `instanceof`, because of the signature:

```
// In Class
public boolean isInstance(Object obj)
```

You want the equivalent of `obj instanceof clazz`, where `obj` can be any object reference, and `clazz` must be a class... so you really *have* to call it as `clazz.isInstance(obj)`.